# Fourier Tansform

Tags: fourier-transform

What will be the Fourier transform of the wave shown below:

[Waveform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19L4h.png)

Basically i want to know the Fourier Transform of a square wave of varying width!

Comment: Your picture just shows one small part of the graph.  What is the rest of it?

Comment: Combine the facts 1) transform of a rectangle is a sinc 2) translation in ordinary domain shifts phase in fourier domain 3) linearity of the transform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be asking for the Fourier Transform of
$$
f(t)=\sum_k a_kp(t-kT_s)
$$
where the $a_k$ are either $0$ or $1$, and:
$$
p(t)=\left\{ \begin{array}{cc}
1,& t\in(0,T_s]\\
0,& \mbox{otherwise}
\end{array}
 \right.
$$
Then, by linearity of the FT and the appropriate translation theorem:
$$
F(\omega)=(\mathcal{F}f)(\omega)=\sum_k a_k e^{i\omega kT_s}P(\omega)=P(\omega)\sum_k a_k e^{i\omega kT_s}
$$
where $P=\mathcal{F}p$.

Note: the sign in the exponents in the sum may be negative if you are using a definition of the forward direction of the FT in the opposite sense to what I have taken.

Comment: ($F(\omega)$ has good chances to be a distribution)